# Manually create @OneToMany script for MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I have an existing EE application that uses EJB3 and is connected to a MySQL database. I basically need to modify some of the entities and then manually script the modifications to the database to implement the modification.

Specifically I need to add the following to an entity called 'TICKET':

```
@OneToMany(cascade = {CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.MERGE, CascadeType.REMOVE})
private List<Attachment> attachements = new ArrayList<>();
```

*NB: The join is unidirectional.*

How would I go about creating the relationship as an SQL statement?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reasonable mapping of this relationship in SQL would be to use foreign keys to limit "parent" entity id values in table mapped to `Attachment` entity:

```
CREATE TABLE attachments (
...
ticket_id INTEGER,
...
FOREIGN KEY (ticket_id) REFERENCES tickets(id) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE
)
```

The direction of join (whether it is unidirectional or bidirectional) would not affect the SQL data structures.